# "She kind of took a pill"

Tags: phrase-meaning

"She kind of took a pill "

What is the meaning of this phrase...did she or did she not take the pill, also is it really necessary to use **kind of** in this phrase?

Comment: Could you provide additional context, please? Without it any answer will need to be a bit speculative

Answer (score 3):

Most probably this means:

> She took a pill, but I don't want to openly admit it, and I do want to minimize the seriousness of it.

But it may mean:

> She didn't take a pill, but she did something similar that I don't want to discuss in detail.

This use of "kind of" would normally occur only in a spoken conversation, or in written dialog. It is something people actually do say, so dialog will include it on proper occasions. It is needed to convey all those unspoken reservations.

Comment: It might also be that kind of tiresome speech you hear these days where people insert extra words 'she kind of, like, took a pill, you know?'

Answer (score 1):

Normally, ***kind of*** is

> used when you are trying to explain or describe something, but you cannot be exact:
>
> - It was *kind of* strange to see him again. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kind-of))

However, depending on the context of your sentence, the uncertainty of "kind of" could indicate ***indolence***, ***hesitation*** (maybe with the intention of ***lying***) or ***fear*** in the speaker.